# How to Parse Query parameters in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a requirement I will get the URL in the format like this below
https://sample.com?first=one&second=two&third=three

How can I form an xml structure below which will be formed by making use of this query parameters

```
<first>one</first><second>two</second><third>three</third>
```

can Please somebody help me with thisand provide me an xslt for this requirement

Comment: You've probably gotten a downvote because you've not shown any effort to do this yourself. You have come here with a requirement rather than a problem - we're here to solve a problem with the code you have, not do your work for you. Have a look at "[*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for some advice.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I will get the URL*"? How exactly will you "get" it and pass it to the XSLT stylesheet?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following **XML** input (note the escaping of the ampersand character):

```
<URL>https://sample.com?first=one&amp;second=two&amp;third=three</URL>
```

the folowing stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(URL, '?')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&amp;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before($token, '=')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, '=')"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <first>one</first>
   <second>two</second>
   <third>three</third>
</output>
```

Note that this will work only if the query field names are also valid XML element names.